# C#, Extensive wage calculation with Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

Here's a description of what I need to do:

Write a program that first initializes arrays via user input with the names and wages of all employees, then prompts the user for the hours worked for each employee and computes their regular pay, overtime pay, gross income, federal tax deduction (10% of gross), state tax deduction (5% of gross), and net income. After the last employee is processed, the program displays totals for regular pay and overtime pay and the names and gross incomes for the employees that earned the most and least amount.

I'm stuck at the if-else statement, I'm fairly new to c# and still don't know a lot, basically I'm stuck, and I'm in a rush to get this done, I would appreciate any help on this.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Exercise3
{
    class ArrayCalculations
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double hours,
                   regularPay,
                   overtimePay,
                   grossPay,
                   netPay,
                   stateTax,
                   fedTax;

            const double FED_TAX = .10;
            const double STATE_TAX = .05;
            const double REG_HOURS = 40.0;
            const double OVERTIME = 1.5;

            string[] name = new string[5];
            double[] wage = new double[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
            {
                Write("Please enter name: ", (i + 1));
                name[i] = ReadLine();

                Write("Please enter your hourly wage: ", (i + 1));
                wage[i] = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());

                Write("Please enter hours worked this week", (i + 1));
                hours = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
            }

            WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
            {
                WriteLine("Name: " + name[i] + "  Wage: " + wage[i]);
            }

            if (hours <= 40)
            {
                regularPay = hours * wage;
                overtimePay = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // ??
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Decompose your solution! *Extract methods*! *Extract classes*, e.g. `Payment` with constructor `Payment(decimal gross)` and properties `Gross`, `Net`, `StateTax`, `FederalTax`...

Comment: `hours = Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());` you NEED `try - catch` here or `Double.TryParse()` . Otherwhise when I insert "test" your program will fail.

Comment: sorry if I'm being a nuisance, but how exactly would I write that in, or rather where would It work best

Comment: I will post an example.

Comment: I appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: By the way if it helps any, my goal at the moment is to figure out how to multiply by any numbers that are input into the wage array, but since it's an array I'm not really sure what to do

Comment: It also says that the hours variable is an 'unassigned local variable', not sure why that's happening either.

Comment: I think you need to get a good grasp of Object Orientated programming. Learn as much as you can about objects, classes, encapsulation, polymorphism and inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much, this is my first Object Oriented language, It's a course that I'm taking at college and I'm scraping by because it's a more difficult than I had imagined, I'm more familiar with quickbasic and html and they were easy for me to learn, but now I'm having so much trouble and I'm trying so hard to learn c# because I don't want to fail the course and I really like c# but I just don't get it   :)

Comment: Don't despair, it can take a little while to 'click'. When it does, it will all make sense though. There are some great resources online, just stick at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Try to split your code into logic pieces:

```
private double CalculateWage(double hours, double wage)
{
    return (hours * wage);
}
```

Or like this:

```
private string GetUserInput_String(string message, int index)
{
    Write(message, index);       
    return ReadLine();
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
name[i] = GetUserInput_String("Please enter name: ", (i + 1))
```

Same for doubles.

```
private string GetUserInput_Double(string message, int index)
{
    try
    {
        Write("Please enter wage: ", (i + 1));            
        return Convert.ToDouble(ReadLine());
        //OR
        double result;
        double.TryParse(ReadLine(),out result);
        if(result != 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) //Catch all thrown Exception
    {
        Write(ex.Message);//Handle Exceptions (log, retry,..)
        return null; //When retunring null check for null when working with the returned value !!!
    }
}
```

2.) Use `Try {} catch {}`

Catch and handle exception **ALWAYS** when casting, converting, etc.

Check out [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb397906.aspx):

```
private void PrintWages(string[] names, double[] wages)
{
    names.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Name: {x} Wage: {wages[names.ToList().IndexOf(x)]}")); 
}
```

This does the following:

```
string[] names = {"Anna", "Peter", "Marc"};
string[] wages = { "1500", "2000", "3500" };
names.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Name: {x} Wage: {wages[names.ToList().IndexOf(x)]}"));

Output:
Name: Anna Wage: 1500
Name: Peter Wage: 2000
Name: Marc Wage: 3500
```

So what have I done here:

```
using System.Linq; -  Adds the "Foreach" and other extension methods to Collections   

array.ToList() => array converted to list

Foreach element in names I called WriteLine();
names.ToList().IndexOf(x) gives me the index of the current element to use in wages[index]
```

I condesed the output via [Interplated Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/dn961160.aspx)

So the more or less complete result would be sth. like this

```
//Care of naming !
            // string[] names - its a sort of collection of names so dont call it name.
            // name would be ONE item of that array

            //I recommend using List<sting> / List<double> here !
            List<string> employees = new List<string>();
            List<double> wages = new List<double>();

            //Or way better => Dictionairy<string, double>(),

            //A Dictionairy has a Key (unique) and a correlating value 
            Dictionary<string, double> EmployeeWages = new Dictionary<string, double>();

            int employeesToAdd = 0;
            try
            {
                Console.Write("How many employees would you like to add ?");
                employeesToAdd = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write($"Error: {ex.Message}");
                return;
            }

            //We reach this line only if employeesToAdd has a value !
            for (int i = 0; i < employeesToAdd; i++)
            {
                EmployeeWages.Add(GetUserInput_String("Please enter name: "), GetUserInput_Double("Please enter your wage: "));
            }


            PrintResult(EmployeeWages);
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I understood a bit of this, I definitely need more practice, but seriously thank you It helped a lot.